# Type-C Male to 2x Type-C Female for mobile

Tags: usb, splitters

I'm looking for small Type-C Male to 2x Type-C Female cable for smartphone (with the possibility of charging). But I really haven't even seen any. Is there an opportunity to find any, do they exist?

Comment: To help your search: what you are asking for is a "USB Type-C hub with charging pass-through". However, they are very new and complex devices, and I doubt you will find one that looks like a "cable" rather than a box (though improvements in the technology in future years might change that).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called "USB Type-C splitter".

It seems that those things do exist, they are just not common yet and I'm not sure if you would be able to use both of the ports for data transmission, but at least you should be able to listen to music over type-c headphones and charge at the same time, as per the item description.

[https://www.amazon.com/MChoice-Capsule-Modeling-Headphone-Splitter/dp/B07H151Y8X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07H151Y8X)

https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/2-1-C-USB-3-1-AUX/32917688534.html

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for. I don't need 3.5mm audio jack, I need two type c ports.

Comment: Did you even look at those products? Those are what you specified: one Type-C male to 2 **physical** Type-C female, with one used for charging and other for Type-C data connection, technically it is a **cable**, since it doesn't have any active circuitry and is made by routing VCC and data lines to two different Type-C ports. If you are looking for a small Type-C **hub** that can transmit data over both ports you should specify it in your question.